# Finding real numbers for sum problem

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, summation

Can you find some real numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ that follow $\sum_{k=1}^n{x_i^q}=q$ for all positive integers $q > 1$? Take $n$ to be some positive integer.

Comment: dont know if you'll find this helpful, but you can easily see that for $n=1$, the answer is no. Do you want to find the answer for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, we want it for all $n$

Comment: Isn't just letting $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=({q\over n})^{1\over q}$ one (trivial) solution? I am not sure if I understand correctly.

Comment: @cr001 no, it isn't, because then $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{i}^{q} = q$ just for one $q > 1$ and not for all $q > 1$ simultaneously.